# How to wrap a value in a new datatype while preserving the typeclass membership?

Tags: haskell

I am an Haskell beginner  writing a toy compiler in Haskell for some simple language, and, after having done the parser, I started working on the first "stages" (type checking, some simplifications, code generation etc). My AST datatype looks something like this:

```
data Ast a = ConstInt Int a | Variable String a | SomeComplexThing .... a
```

The point being, I wish to use that `a` slot for storing information after each pass: say, after the parsing we have a `Ast Position`, then after type checking we have a `Ast (Position,TypeInfo)` and so on and so forth.

However, I wish to access the values in this payload independently on the stage. As of right now, at different stages, the tuple is of a different type and therefore there is no homogenous automated way to do this. If I am to remove a stage, all is to be changed.

So, the haskell noob in me thought:Typeclasses!

Now, I can easly make a `TypeInfoHolder` typeclass, and a `PositionHolder` typeclass, and so on

```
class TypeInfoHolder a where
  getTypeInfo::a->TypeInfo
```

And have a

```
  data TypeInfoHolderObj a = TypeInfoHolderObj a TypeInfo
```

and make that an instance of `TypeInfoHolder`.

Now I want somehow to automatically ensure that each `TypeInfoHolderObj a` is also an instance of all the classes which `a` belongs to, that is, for each typeclass `A` which `a` implements, then `TypeInfoHolderObj a` also implements by applying the class's functions to the `a` member of the `TypeInfoHolderObj`

I'd just want to know this out of curiosity: it seems the sort of thing that could come up quite often.

Comment: Why not simply create a new datatype for each stage (instead of using tuples), containing the relevant attributes (position, type info, etc), and define for each of these datatypes the instances of the type classes you need for that stage?

Comment: I think that's what I will end up doing. I guess I have to remember that just because haskell is "fancy as hell",sometimes it's just better to keep it simple

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have roughly two questions.

1. Is it a good idea to use typeclasses to provide the ability to project a certain type out of many others? And,
2. Is there a way to make types like `TypeInfoHolderObj a` inherit all of the instances of `a`

The answer to (1) is a little contested because the "right" use of typeclasses is a little contested. Personally, I think the answer is "yes" and it's backed up a bit in the Lenses literature where typeclasses like `HasX` are common. This is definitely a stylistic concern, though, so it will be difficult to get a meaningful answer—especially from Stack Overflow.

The answer to (2) is "no" and it's easy to show why. Consider just one of many example instances which would need to be automatically derived

```
instance Monoid a => Monoid (TypeInfoHolderObj a) where ...
```

For some types (those which could be `newtypes`) this instance derivation can be done automatically (see `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`) but for `TypeInfoHolderObj` it is not possible unless `TypeInfo` *also* shares the `Monoid` instance. If it did, we could do

```
  mempty = TypeInfoHolderObj mempty mempty
  mappend (TypeInfoHolderObj a b) (TypeInfoHolderObj c d) = 
    TypeInfoHolderObj (mappend a c) (mappend b d)
```

In general, we don't know all of the assumptions required to automatically derive instances like this. It's possible to guess when they might occur, though, as you can expect them to work whenever your instances look a bit like

```
class Foo a where ...
instance (Foo a, Foo b) => Foo (a, b) where ...
```

since, effectively, `TypeInfoHolderObj a` is nothing more than `(a, TypeInfo)`.

Comment: Note that there's an open proposal concerning (1) that will make HasX-style type classes (and type families) be automatically generated by GHC (as part of improved record syntax).  Given the support I've heard for it, it seems like the community is rallying around this use of type classes.